# Laravel migrate - without deleting tables that are not defined in migrations?

Tags: laravel

That is - treating tables, which do not have migrations/schemas in my applications as something that app cannot touch?.. I'm dealing with a big database, and I want to experiment with creating and editing new tables, but I'm worried that I could mess up something else while using migrate command.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Do a backup first then you can experiment. Actually Laravel migrations normally create a table called migrations in the database, here the activities of you migrations and the table concerned are written so it can easily do other actions such as rollback, update, create new, check other stuffs so it should be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration command (`php artisan migrate`) will only do what you write in the migrations. No need to worry that it will not touch any table that you have not specified explicitly.
But even with that fact, it is important to perform a backup before you feel even more secure.

Migration docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations

Comment: But are there any pitfalls, like name collisions?

Comment: @bruddah Any inconsistency errors between your new migrations and the existing structure will only result in the failure of your migration. Remember to also configure the downs methods of your migrations so that if the result is not as expected, you can come back with `php artisan migrate:rollback`.

Comment: Thanks, paying extra attention when dropping tables and adding a prefix to new tables seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I have one production database for several projects.  To avoid any issues like you've described, I add a 'prefix' to each project.

In config/database.php

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'prefix' => 'appname_',
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-table-prefixes-in-laravel?page=0

Comment: How would I access tables, that do not have 'appname_' prefix? I need to be able to read from original tables.

Answer (score 0):

Making migrations for the tables is a good practice as typing few lines of code can reflect huge changes in the database when using **migrations**.
Manually handling database operations is a tiresome task. Therefore, I suggest you to use migrations for each table in your database.